# Change css of input element followed by an error div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input element with a select class that, in case of an error, gets followed by a div with an error class. When that happens I want to change the background color of the input element. This is what I came up with but it doesn't work:

```
$( "div.error" ).prev( "input[type=text].select" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
```

Thank you!!

Comment: ... `background-color` instead?

Comment: Your code works fine for me ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhmv8/)). Maybe the JS is executed before the `error` or `select` classes are added to the elements? Or is there another element between the `input` and the `div`? (check in dev tools)